# custom dynamic list_filter with Django SimpleListFilter

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

According to [Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) it is possible to write custom list filter by creating "a class inheriting from django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter, which you need to provide the title and parameter_name attributes to and override the lookups and queryset methods, e.g."
some thing like this:

```
from datetime import date

from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class CustomListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
  title = _('filendName_amount')
  parameter_name = 'amount'

  filed_name = 'filed_name'
  compare_value = 100000

  def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (
        ('mt', _('more than ') + str(self.compare_value)),
        ('lt', _('less than ') + str(self.compare_value)),
    )

  def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    kwargs = {}
    if self.value() == 'mt':
        kwargs = {
            '{0}__{1}'.format(self.filed_name, 'gte'): self.compare_value,
        }
    if self.value() == 'lt':
        kwargs = {
            '{0}__{1}'.format(self.filed_name, 'lte'): self.compare_value,
        }
    return queryset.filter(**kwargs)
```

It works fine. But is it possible to pass the filed_name and the compare_value to create more dynamic list filter for do not copy and past the code and reuse it in many admin models with different field names and different compare values?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to input the field_name and compare_value as plain text, or can they be a list of choices as well?

Comment: No, I just want to prevent to copy code. @NicoGriffioen

Comment: In that case you can just subclass CustomListFilter, and set field_name and compare_value to a different value.